# Simple C++ conversation

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have this program and I would like to know how to continue it. I want to have the user input more text after "what's up" and then have the program respond. Thank you for any help

```
int main()
 {
    cout << "Hello \n";

    char answer = 0;
    cin >> answer;

    switch(answer)
    {
      case 'h':
        cout << "What's up \n";
        break;
      case 'g':
        cout << "Bye \n";
        break;
      default:
        cout << "Not a valid response. \n";
        break;
 }
}
```

Comment: You're not very clear about what your goal is, could you clarify a bit?

Comment: In everyday conversation after you ask "what's up" the person you're talking to replies with something. I want to have the user type something in and then have the program say "interesting" or something.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a great time to have functions. Create one that continues the conversation and call it after "what's up":

```
void continueConversation() { .... }

case 'h':
    cout << "What's up \n";
    continueConversation();
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a while loop so that the conversation continues until the user says "Bye"?

```
// convert bye to up/downcase, and all words for that matter when checking
while(answer != "bye")
{
    if(answer == "hello")
    ...
    cin >> answer;
}
```

Or something to that effect.

Example for you, using your code

```
int main() {
cout << "Hello \n";

char answer = 0;
cin >> answer;
while(answer != 'b') // b for bye
  switch(answer)
  {
    case 'h':
      cout << "What's up \n";
      break;
    case 'b':
      cout << "Bye \n";
      break;
    default:
      cout << "Not a valid response. \n";
      break;
  }
  cin >> answer;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to create, I'm sorry to say, it will take a lot more than you think to compile a fully sophisticated  chat bot. You could create a ' vector phrases` and store as many phrases as you want in it, and use a PRNG to decide which phrases to be outputted. However, you would also have to write some safeguard statements that allow the phrases to make sense to the user when they communicate with the program. It is very daunting how complex such would be compared to your start.